# Seamless mode for remote desktop software

Tags: desktop, remote, teamviewer, mode, seamless

Are there any remote desktop applications that make it possible to view [each window from one desktop] separately in another desktop (like "seamless mode" in Virtualbox?) I want to view each application window from a remote computer separately.

Comment: What OS is running on the 'server'?

Comment: Neither of the operating systems are hosted on a server. What does "server" refer to in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/). 
It's very complete, easy to use and available in almost any platform.

Also in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) you have a comparison among all the remote desktop software. One of the fields is seamless window.

Answer (score 3):

If you're coming from a Unix-like environment, Rdesktop >= 1.5 has a seamless option. You'll need a couple of supporting bits on the remote server, but they're free and source is available -- http://www.cendio.com/seamlessrdp/

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "supporting bits on the remote server?"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Citrix. It has an application mode as well as a desktop mode. In application mode, the remote application presents its windows separately on the local desktop.

There is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226772/can-rdp-clients-launch-remote-applications-and-not-desktops as well.

For VNC, [MetaVNC](http://metavnc.sourceforge.net/)

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software) WikiPedia article may also help.

Answer (score 1):

In Remote Utilities (http://www.remoteutilities.com) you can switch between a tabbed mode and a separate window mode, if that's what you mean.

Hope that helps.